# Magento 2.3.3 migration from 1.9.2.3 - Setting migration error

Tags: migration, magento2.3.3, magento2-migration-tool

Magento 2.3.3 migrate from Magento 1.9.2.3 getting an error,

```
In Config.php line 70:

  Invalid config filename: vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensource-  
  to-opensource\1.9.2.3\config.xml
```

Live website migrate into my localhost Centos7-Nginx server Magento 2.3.3,

Localhost Magento home page URL : **192.168.1.64:8085**

How to solve the error?

**config.xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_DataMigrationTool:etc/config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Inventory Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Inventory\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Inventory\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Inventory Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Inventory\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="547.25.365.254" name="magentolivedb" user="username" password="mypassword" />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="192.168.1.64" name="gta" user="root" password="P@ssword123" />
    </destination>
    <options>
        <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.3/map.xml</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.3/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix />
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.9.2.3</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <!-- <crypt_key /> -->
        <crypt_key>rigregnreughrgr9ehgerhg9rhgr9ehg8r9hre</crypt_key>
    </options>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used the incorrect **slash path character**, so the *file path can not be detected.*

Running this on Ubuntu:
`bin/magento migrate:data  app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.7.0.2/config12.xml`

Gives the following result : 
`Invalid config filename: app/code/GloLightingOverrides/Magento_DataMigrationTool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.7.0.2/config12.xml`

**Notice the slash result, compare against your error result**

(It does not seem that `\` (even when escaped) can work, tested with **ls app\code** or **ls app\code** gives : `cannot access 'app\code': No such file or directory`  )

NOTE: Obviously I do not want to rerun migrate:data on my current installation, but this is my conclusion.

Comment: After successfully migrate setting, if i try to migrate data i am getting following error [NOTICE]: You can use --auto or -a option to ignore not mapped differences between source and destination to continue migration
In Data.php line 97:
                          
  Integrity Check failed

Comment: It means that you have not mapped everything (tables, optional attributes etc).  Take that output result; it would give you all the tables that are not mapped, add them into the map.xml of your version.

Also, you would need to restart the **data migration** process.  (You do not need to rerun migrate:settings again).  As of current versions the eav step with --reset will only work **before** any attributes were imported.  

Otherwise, please follow my suggested solution here : [github](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/813#issuecomment-634719725)

Comment: I just run the command with --auto, no error , command competed if i did wrong how to revert my all changes?

Comment: Please follow the github link I provided above for reference.  If you received no error on `migrate:data` then you can proceed for now.  If your migration fails and you want to restart from the beginning, the guide there would help you.  Lots of trial and error with this one.  Good luck